# Possible to set the value of a javascript function parameter in a callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

That title was a mouthful.  Here's what I'm trying to do in code below.  The callback in this case is in the jQuery $.get function.

```
      function getMapMarkup(loadUrl, myVar) {
        me = myVar;
        $.get(
            loadUrl,
            { var1: "hello", var2: "world" },
            function(responseText) {
              me = responseText;
              myVar = me; //doesn't work.  
            },
            "html"
         );     
        }
```

Is there a way to change the value of `myVar` in the `function(responseText)` callback, so I can use it in my program later on?  Or is there another (better) way to go about what I'm trying to do?

Comment: It _does_ work, except that the AJAX call happens asynchronously, so that by the time that function finishes, the rest of your script has already run without receiving the new value for `myVar` yet.

Comment: Most likely you are accessing myVar even before the callback is executed. Remember, `$.get` is an AJAX call which is asynchronous and so the callback function will be called later after your server responded.

Comment: the easiest (but not the best) solution would be to make your ajax call synchronous by passing `async: false`. In order to do this though, you would need to use `$.ajax` instead of `$.get`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by *`later on`* you mean immediately after the `$.get` call then no, there is no way because AJAX is asynchronous and the `$.get` returns immediately and the success callback can be executed much later. The only reliable way to know when this happens is to put the code that depends on its result **inside** the `success` callback. You could also call some other function inside the success callback passing it the result of the AJAX call.

Comment: Thanks gentlemen.  I know due to the async nature of $.get I wouldn't be able to set myVar right away, but was hoping to somehow "have access to it" in the callback so when the time came I could set and use it when $.get was done.
The reason for all this is to use the myVar variable to update the DOM when ready, in the following way: $("#myDiv").html(myVar).  
I'll take your suggestions to heart, thanks again.

Comment: ..I should also add that part of the reason for this is I want to cache the value of `myVar`, so that I don't need to call $.get again if `myVar` has html in it already (say, if a device's orientation changes.)  So I wanted to call it like var `myHtml =null; getMapMarkup(someURL, myHtml)`.. and save the resulting value in `myHtml` for later use.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are accessing `myVar` before the callback is executed.

`$.get` makes an AJAX call which is asynchronous and so the callback function will be called later after your server responded and so any immediate access to `myVar` will not have the updated value.